# Chose View in MVC depending on table value

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatables

Been struggling with an problem a while now witch i hope someone here can help me with. I have made an program in Visual studio 2017 that show tv-program for 5 channels. My data is stored in one table in my database and connected with entity framework. My tabledata look like this:

```
Id  Channel   Program       Date               Time         
1      1       News         2018-11-12         20:00
2      1      Die Hard      2018-11-12         22:00
3      2       Boxing       2018-11-12         09:00
4      3       Soccer       2018-11-12         11:00
.      .         .                .               .
.      .         .                .               .
```

So my Model in VS is TvShow and their properties is listed above.

I want to be able to click on my program (actionlink) and when i do that i come to that channel specific tv-tableau! (5 different views) So if i click on Boxing i will come to channel 2 list of program.

So i guess i want to solve the problem by reading the channel properties to come to the right view! (maybe if-statement?)

Anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: What about making 1 view that can display the choosen channel? What if you want to upgrade your application and add 300 channels? You certainly don't wan't to manually create 300 views

Comment: `return View(YourViewNameAsStringHere, yourmodelhere);`

Comment: No,i know,  it´s not the best way to design the program. I Have a table for each channel also , and one with all five (6 tables in total) I had problem to join does five so that is the reason why i have one table with all channels also..

Comment: return view().. do you mean to write this in @htm.actionlink?